# for in range - возвращает лишь 1 значение а не 100

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу парсер, для этого мне нужно сгенерировать 100 адресов страниц, и выполнить функцию "парсинга" те же 100 раз. Я сделал упрощенный код и конструкцию что бы разобраться в этом. Но вместо ожидаемого результата в получении 2,3,4,5,6 ... 100 значений, и выполнении конечной функции pi() 100 раз, я получаю вывод функции pi() лишь один раз.
В примере  #return get_var(page) - закоментировано - что бы продемонстрировать что без "return" я получаю все эти значения, а вот если раскоментировать и пробрасывать дальше по функциям то ничего не выходит.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



def pi(page):
    print(page)


def get_var(page): 
     print("Вторая функция %d" % (page))
     return pi(page)



def set_var():
    for page in range(2, 100 + 1):
        print("set_var %d" % (page))
        #return get_var(page)



if __name__ == "__main__":    
    set_var();
```

Comment: После того как вы выполните `return` выполнение функции, а также всех циклов, который она содержала, прекращается.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно подробнее - что мне сделать что бы достичь результата и функция передала 100 раз переменную - и 100 раз с этой переменной выполнилась функция pi() - она у меня будет парсить по очереди все эти 100 страниц.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает просто `get_var(page)` вместо `return get_var(page)` ?

Comment: Все гениальное просто! Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Удачи в изучении Python :)

Comment: Сергей, скажите - а с "парсингом" - в таком ключе не будет "зависаний" программы - потому что сгенерировать 100 страниц это одна секунда или меньше, а вот в этой конструкции - питон и библиотеки будут посылать 100 запросов по очереди с разницей милисекунду на адрес сервера - или они будут "ждать" загрузки и выполнения инструкции в функции?

Comment: Думаю вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос и там все подробно описать. Не могу вам ответь, т.к. не понимаю что у вас за "парсинг" и куда вы его отсылаете.

Comment: Спасибо! Пока не буду тревожить сообщество лишними "теоритическими" вопросами - лучше поэксперементирую и посмотрю как работать будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сразу скажу что я не силён в Python но могу сказать что когда вы ставите return  то функция заканчивает своё действие и возвращает значение get_var(page) 1 раз. 
def pi(page):
    print(page)

```
def get_var(page): 
     print("Вторая функция %d" % (page))
     return pi(page)



def set_var():
    for page in range(2, 100 + 1):
        print("set_var %d" % (page))
        get_var(page)

set_var()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы прямо паралельно двоем мне помогли!